# operator << strange behaviour

Tags: c++, stream

I have a class called Log, which overload the operator <<:

```
class Log
{
     public:
        static void init(std::ostream&);
        Log(const std::string&);
        ~Log(); //Write to the log here
        Log& operator<<(bool);
        Log& operator<<(const std::string&);

     private:
        std::stringstream text;
        static std::ostream *stream;
        std::string tag;
};
```

Ok, here is the problem, when i write to the log like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("log.txt",std::ios::app);
    Log::init(file);
    Log("[INFO]") << "Test";
    file.close();
}
```

The operator<< which receives a bool is called, that write true to the log..., if i delete the operator implementation which receives a bool then the other one is called correctly.
I think this happens because the char* can be interpreted as bool... but how can i fix it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a third `operator<<` overload that takes a `char *` parameter.

I think your analysis of the problem is probably correct, although surprising.

Comment: *"although surprising"* - Standard conversions (such as pointer to `bool`) have higher priority than user-defined conversions (such as pointer to `std::string`).

Comment: @ChristianRau, while it might be correct to the letter of the standard it still flies in the face of common sense.

Comment: Indeed it does. The main problem is that strings are not first class citizens in C or C++.

Comment: There's one more strange thing hehe, i'm on a project which implements the Log like the one i wrote before, but it doesn't have the problem with the boolean :/, sure i'm missing something in the operator implementations of the class ....

Comment: @DGomez, sorry I can't help with that one unless you give more details or start a new question.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible `<<` operators, one taking a `std::string`, and one taking a `bool`. The first requires a user-defined conversion, constructing a `std::string` object from a `char` array. The second requires a standard conversion, converting a pointer to a `bool` (null pointer becomes false, non-null pointer becomes true). The rule here is that a standard conversion is better than a user-defined conversion (13.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank] /2), so the compiler chooses the `bool` version.

Answer (score 1):

You may drop all operator << in your class and have a template:

```
template <typename T> 
Log& operator << (Log& log, const T& value) {
    // ...
    return log;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace <<(bool) by <<(OnlyBool), with OnlyBool defined as:

```
struct OnlyBool
{
    OnlyBool(bool b)  : m_b(b){}
    bool m_b;
};
```

The idea is to use a type that is implicitly created from bool, but only bool.

(Sorry for the terseness, I'm writing this on my phone)